# Revert 8788 Patch on CE 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788

I am having to revert Security Patch 8788 due to it not applying the patch properly. I have noticed that when I have tried the command

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh -R

PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

I have had a look further down for example and it says

```
The next patch, when reversed, would delete the file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php,
which does not exist!  Ignore -R? [n]
```

I have replaced the files that were deleted by the Patch and when I have tried running the revert patch command, it has not reverted the patch. I have checked the applied patches file and

```
-e 2016-11-01 11:59:58 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.12 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-          1533_EE_1.12_v1.patch | REVERTED
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
```

When I have tried adding the Magento files that 1533 removes it now says:

```
    sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh 
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2014-10-03-04-00-32.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.rej
```

I am not sure what to do here. As I assumed it would be a simple process of reverting the security patch. I am using GitHub and doing it all via Version Control, is there a method I could use via that?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by adding the files from this website: https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh/ Its basically all of the files but without running the shell script.

I replaced all of the files via version control, and then uploaded it, downloaded the files and the site is now showing as patched by MageReport.